# Filtering posts in category by tag URL

Tags: categories, taxonomy, tags

I'm still learning WP, so this might seem pretty obvious to veterans.

I've been given admin rights to a WordPress site and told to replicate what my predecessor did with a specific pair of pages.

These two pages show a number of posts that belong to a specific category (catA). Additionally, each page further filters the posts by their respective tag (tag1 and tag2).

What's weird is that the URL of the two pages shows their tag, not the category. Example: www.examplewpsite.com/tag/tag1/

My guess is that there's a defined link between the category and the tags, and have even found styling for the category that acts on the tags, but I am unsure of how to add more tags to this link.

If anyone can point me in the right direction to find and edit this link, it would be a huge help.

Comment: A wild guess is that there might be a function that filters the posts for the tag taxonomy page for that category.  Look in the functions.php for a function that uses the hook 'pre_get_posts' -  such as: add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'some_function_name' ).   If you find this and need more info, go here:  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/

Comment: @LeoraDeans Nope, nothing like that in the functions.php file

Comment: Only other suggestion, then, would be to see if there is a unique archive template for tags.  In Appearance -> Theme Editor, look for a file called 'tag.php' or 'tag-tag1.pnp.  (Alternatively, the plugin,Show Current Template (JOTAKI Taisuke) is a super-useful tool for telling you, as the admin, exactly which templates a page is using.).  If the tag archive has a unique template, other than the default archive.php, then some unique filtering of posts may be there.